# Configure Electron/Node To Run In Debug And Attach a Debugger

Tags: node.js, electron, webstorm

I'm a Java developer but I have to try and debug a Node based application which runs inside Electron. I use IntelliJ IDEA for Java development/debugging and have WebStorm for which I want to debug the JS application.

As a Java developer I am used to starting the JVM/Tomcat/OSGi container in debug mode to which I can attach IntelliJ as my debugger. This allows me to dynamically add breakpoints *without* modifying code in IntelliJ. I want to be able to do the same with the Electron application but I haven't been able to work out how to do this.

I have tried starting Election with the `--inspect` option as detailed [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process) but cannot attach WebStorm to it. I've also tried setting up a run time configuration in WebStorm itself which works as far as starting Electron but terminates with the error 'connection refused'.

I've also used [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html) and [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm/) to try and attach a debugger but to no avail. I also have to work on Windows so I'm facing having to deal with inadequate tools to determine if Electron is listening on a port.

**Update**

I can't put complete code here but I would start the application with:

`npm run dev`

And this is the relevant part `package.json` in the root folder of the application but WITHOUT any debugging options specified:

```
"dev": "concurrently --raw --kill-others \"npm run dev-server\" \"npm run start\"",
"dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline",
"start": "cross-env WEBPACK_ENV=dev electron .",
```

The application starts up i.e. the Election window appears but terminates before it is completely rendered. I can't say for sure how far into the start-up it gets before failing.

**Update 2**

I've modified the `package.json` file `dev` and `start` lines to:

```
"dev": "concurrently --raw --kill-others \"npm run %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% dev-server\" \"npm run %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% start\"",
"start": "cross-env WEBPACK_ENV=dev electron --inspect=5858 --remote-debugging-port=9223 .",
```

But still get `Connection refused`.

Comment: How far do you get into the start? Also there are two process you need to debug with electron the main process (electron itself) and the render process (the browser instance) `--remote-debugging-port=9223` will add remote debugging for the renderer btw,

Comment: *"I also have to work on Windows so I'm facing having to deal with inadequate tools to determine if Electron is listening on a port."* What is wrong with `netstat`?

Comment: @HansKoch Added some additional information. I will try the additional options you mentioned. I have not seen the remote debug port option anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

To debug Electron main process, you need using **Node.js** run configuration; for render process, the **Attach to Node.js/Chrome** configuration is required.

Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/getting-started-with-electron-in-webstorm/ for more info

Comment: Hi lena, thanks fro your answer. After following the link you provided I still haven't been able to attach a debugger either to the main or render process. When attaching to the main the application just terminates after start-up and for the render process it 'appears' to attach but no break points are hit. I might be being stupid here but trying to attach a debugger  shouldn't be this difficult. Node/NPM/electron seem to make this far too difficult an non-obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I found that WebStorm can debug the main process properly if electron is started with the flag:

```
electron . --serve --inspect-brk=5893
```

Note the 'brk', it stops the process until a debugger is attached.

Then I just created a run configuration (Attach to Node.js/Chrome) and specified the 5893 port, telling to reconnect automatically.